# How do I get Power Upped in Pushmo Studio?

Tags: pushmo

In Pushmo studio, I try to scan QR codes, but the old man says that it is too advanced for me. How do I get Powered up to get advanced stages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to beat puzzles. When you've cleared about 70% of the game, you'll be able to play 32x32 puzzles.

Note that skipping stages wont work.

Comment: yup! It really did!